# Spring Boot: Requiring an external (environment-specific) application.properties file

Tags: spring-boot, configuration

Our application needs environment-specific configuration, notably to access the right database. Since the file with that configuration should not be versioned, the project's "code" only contains an [application.properties file](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.1.0/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files) which itself imports another application.properties file. The latter can be in different locations, depending at least on the operating system.

So we basically have

```
spring.config.import=
 optional:file:C:/Devl/Conf_ServicesInternes/application.properties,
 optional:file:/usr/local/tomcat/app_dev/conf/application.properties,
 optional:file:/usr/local/tomcat/app/conf/application.properties
```

`optional` is used since each instance only has one of these files.

The problem with that approach is that if none of these files are present, startup proceeds and eventually fails somewhat cryptically, rather than reporting that an application.properties file is missing.

Activating a profile as [this article](http://www.masterspringboot.com/configuration/various-configuration/importing-properties-from-an-external-file-in-spring-boot/) describes would be an option; I am just wondering if there is a simple solution, like an "or" in `spring.config.import` instead of *optional*.